Lower bound function with first non-zero derivative
Let $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb{R}_+$ be real analytic. In other words, it has a convergent Taylor Series/Power series (but may have complex coefficients). Additionally, impose the following conditions on $f$:
$1. f(0) = 0$.
$2. f(x) \ne 0$ for all $x\ne 0$.
Moreover, let $n$ be the smallest non-zero integer such that $f^{(n)}(0) \ne 0$. Furthermore, let $a$ be such that $(a,f(a))$ is the closest relative minimum to $(0,0)$. Does the following hold:
$$
f(x) \geq \frac{f(a)}{a^n} x^n, \quad x\in [0,a].
$$
$\textbf{Ideas.}$ Playing around on Mathematica makes me believe this is true, but it seems tricky to prove.

If $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$, the Taylor series at a point of $[0,1]$ can't have non-real coefficients.

You're right. It is just a standard Taylor series with real valued coefficients.

$0$ itself is a local minimum, but I guess you're not counting that.  But your conjecture doesn't make sense to me.  Let's say $f'(0) > 0$ so $n=1$, and $a=1$.  You're claiming $f(x) \ge f(1) x$ for $0 \le x \le 1$?  What about a function like $ 8 x^4 - 20 x^3 + 13 x^2 + 2 x$?

so the assumptions are that $f(x)>0, x \in (0,1]$ and $f$ has a minimum there (so not $0$) in addition to having $f(x)=x^n \sum_{k \ge 0}a_kx^k, a_0>0$. Note that $f$ can easily be increasing so have no other minimum on the interval, but the post seems to suggest that a minimum is assumed so maybe add that specifically as a hypothesis to avoid confusion

@RobertIsrael Thanks for the counter-example.

@Conrad Thanks for pointing that out. The counter-example is relevant to what I'm working on. I know instead of $f(a)/a^n$, a coefficient dependent on the derivatives of $f$ actually work; however, I was curious if there was a worse bound dependent on pointwise evaluation also exists.
